# Create a menu from database (mixed sub menus)

Tags: php, html

I created a database to store a menu informations with 3 level (2 sub menus level).
You can see it on the left here : https://volt-services.fr/sites/stge/index.php#

Here is the table in the database:

[image]

And the code to translate it to HTML:

```php
<?php 

$req = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY ordered"); 

foreach ($req as $r) { 

  if($r->level == 1) {

    $tab[$r->ordered] = array($r->id,$r->name,$r->class,$r->icon);
    
  } elseif ($r->level == 2) {

    $tab[$r->parent][4][$r->ordered] = array($r->id,$r->name);

  } elseif ($r->level == 3) {

    $tab[$r->cat][4][$r->parent][2][$r->ordered] = array($r->id,$r->name);

  }

}

foreach ($tab as $key => $value) {

?>

<li data-menu="<?= $value[0]; ?>" class="<?= $value[2]; ?> menu-item">
<span class="material-icons-outlined"><?= $value[3];  ?></span>  
<span class="titre_menu">&nbsp;<?= $value[1]; ?></span>

    <ul id="sub_menu<?= $value[0]; ?>" class="box_sub_exp <?= $value[2]; ?>">

    <?php foreach ($value[4] as $ke => $val) { // SUB MENU POSITION 4 ?>

        <li class="<?= $value[2]; ?> submenu-item"><a href="page.php?=<?= $val[0]; ?>"><?= $val[1]; ?></a>

      <?php if(!empty($val[2])) { // IS A MENU IN POSITION 2 ?> 

            <ul class="box_sub_sub_exp">

        <?php foreach ($val[2] as $k => $v) { // SUB MENU POSITION 2 ?>
        
                <li class="<?= $value[2]; ?> submenu-item"><a href="page.php?=<?= $v[0]; ?>"><?= $v[1]; ?></a></li>
  
        <?php } ?>

            </ul>

      <?php } ?>

        </li>

  <?php } ?>

    </ul>

</li>

<?php } ?>

</ul>
</nav>


 </section>
```

On the first sub menu everything is OK. But on the second, the first line is missing, on the third 2 first lines are missing, etc...
I think there is a problem with my loop, could you please help me to find it ?

FIXED : the problem was in the request, not "ORDER BY ordered" but by "id"

Comment: How are the submenus mixed? What is the exact problem that you have?

Comment: What does "mixed" mean? You need to show an example of what output you get, and what you expected instead, based on the sample data you've provided. (Don't expect us to go and look at it on your site, because once you fix it, it will no longer be useful for anyone looking at the question in the future. Questions which don't contain a complete example _within them_ get closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: @LajosArpad : I edited my post with more explainations and you can see the problem here : https://volt-services.fr/sites/stge/index2.php

Comment: @ADyson : I edited my post, you prefer screeshots instead of links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you set a numeric key with $r->ordered, you have to sort your table before your display loop !
Give a numeric key to a table line doesn't "auto-sort" it on loop.

Try using [ksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) on $tab before your display foreach. So it's will use keys you've define and sort your table in order.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but "mixed" was not the right word. I edited my post with more informations, it is a problem in my first foreach loop..

Comment: I can't understand the result you're looking for... I'm french too, add me on Discord if you're really stuck so I can "direct" help you (and in french) : Eponime#1103

Comment: Sorry but I can't find you on Discord.. Mine is : Themiller#2519